# Search icon inside a text box

Tags: html, css, search

How to add a search icon inside a search text box quite similar to the Facebook search field. I am a newbie and would need help/suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using CSS

```
#searchBox{
  width: 260px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #FBFBFB;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-position: 270px -10px;
  background-image: url(http://www.kirupa.com/images/search.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

And Here is your HTML

```
<input type="text" id="searchBox"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you were looking for?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trs1unqf/)

If so here is the code,

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="search">
```

CSS:

```
#search {
   width: 300px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #2189C8;
   border-radius: 3px;
   background: url('http://cliparts.co/cliparts/rTL/n8R/rTLn8RLBc.png') no-repeat right center;
   background-size: 20px;
}
```